# Is it possible to have autocompletion for properties in org-agenda?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, filtering, org-properties

When filtering entries in agenda buffer (including C-c m) I only get auto-completion for tags. But the first thing I want to filter by is always the value of the "Project" property. I set up buttons for a few projects in my main org file but they are somewhat cumbersome to use - I'd much rather prefer to open a general agenda buffer and filter from there.

Is it possible to filter agenda by property without typing out the entire name of the property?

For example I have an entry in a form:

```
* #10045 Do some very important fix
:PROPERTIES:
:Project: My project
:END:
```

And I want to have the auto-completion for the name of the property itself and then all the "Project" values that Emacs found in the agenda files. I can settle for a solution that suggests projects from the current buffer only.

The input I want to enter inside the agenda buffer to find the headings with property "Project=My project" would be: `/ P TAB M TAB RET`

Right now to get the desired action I need to type letter by letter (including outer quotes): `/ "Project=\"My project\"" RET` in the regex filter.

EDIT:

I found out that in org-mode I can press `C-c / p` to filter entries by property with auto-completion for property name and property value. I remember now that this was the reason why I set up my org entries in this way. I want to do exactly the same thing but inside agenda buffer. I also found that if I only want to filter by projects (not ideal but it somewhat helps), I can define "Category" property and filter by category in agenda.

Comment: Yes it is possible. You could install the Vertico package, which works well with other packages such as Orderless, Marginalia and Consult.

Comment: @crocefisso could you elaborate? I tried all those packages and they seem to just be using the autocompletion that is already present in Emacs when pressing tab. I still need to type out an entire regexp when filtering by project.

Comment: I have the mentioned packages installed and active. When I do `C-c a m`, if I want to filter by the property `gnu_linux_arch`, I just have to type `arc TAB RET`. Maybe I didn't get your question. If this is the case, could you add a minimal example?

Comment: I think you have properties and tags mixed up. I'll add an example in a minute.

Comment: Indeed, after `C-c a m`, auto completion works for tags but not for properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using [`org-super-agenda`](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-super-agenda)

To get this

***`M-x org-agenda` in `org-super-agenda-mode`***

[image: M-x org-agenda in org-super-agenda-mode]

on these agenda files

***`/tmp/ox-odt.org`***

```
* TODO Upgrade "factory styles" of ODT and ODS exporter :odsexport:odtexport:
:PROPERTIES:
:PROJECT:  odt
:URL:      https://github.com/kjambunathan/org-mode-ox-odt/issues/251
:END:


* TODO Review heuristics used for embedding screenshots in a landscape document :odtexport:
:PROPERTIES:
:PROJECT: odt
:URL:      https://github.com/kjambunathan/org-mode-ox-odt/issues/261
:END:
```

***`/tmp/ox-ods.org`***

```
* TODO Unable to convert a ods file to a tsv file                 :odsexport:
:PROPERTIES:
:PROJECT: ods
:URL:      https://github.com/kjambunathan/org-mode-ox-odt/issues/235
:END:


* Add support for vmax, vmin etc                                  :odsexport:
:PROPERTIES:
:PROJECT: ods
:URL: https://github.com/kjambunathan/org-mode-ox-odt/issues/253
:END:
```

do this

```lisp
(require 'org-super-agenda)
(custom-set-variables
 '(vertico-mode t)
 '(org-agenda-files
   '("/tmp/ox-odt.org"
     "/tmp/ox-ods.org"))
 '(org-super-agenda-groups '((:auto-property "PROJECT")))
 '(org-super-agenda-mode t))
```

Comment: This looks great, I'll try it as soon as I'll have some free time.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. Is there a way to interactively hide certain groups when I'm already in agenda mode or narrow it to just one?

Answer (score 1):

If you are averse to using `org-super-agenda` you can go with the below recipe ...

*(Note that there is no harm in using `org-super-agenda-mode` though)*

*(Note that this "pollutes" `org-tags-history`. So, refine the recipe further if this "pollution" confuses you. You may want to periodically do `(setq org-tags-history nil)` just to be sure that there is ZERO pollution)*

To get this

[image]

followed by

[image]

```lisp
;; Recipe for `emacs -Q`

(require 'subr-x)
(require 'map)

(setq package-user-dir "~/.emacs.d/elpa/")
(package-initialize)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c h") 'consult-history)


(custom-set-variables
 '(vertico-mode t)
 '(org-agenda-files
   '("/tmp/ox-odt.org"
     "/tmp/ox-ods.org")))

(require 'org-agenda)
(setq my-org-agenda-prop-filters
      (thread-last
        org-agenda-files
        (seq-mapcat
         (lambda (it)
           (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect it)
             (thread-last (org-element-map
                              (org-element-parse-buffer)
                              'property-drawer #'identity)
                          (seq-mapcat (lambda (it) (org-element-map it 'node-property #'cadr)))
                          (seq-map (pcase-lambda ((map :key :value)) (cons key value)))
                          (seq-group-by #'car)
                          (seq-map (pcase-lambda (`(,prop . ,prop-and-values))
                                     (cons prop (thread-last prop-and-values
                                                             map-values))))
                          (seq-mapcat
                           (pcase-lambda (`(,prop . ,values))
                             (thread-last values
                                          (seq-map
                                           (lambda (it)
                                             (format "%s=\"%s\"" prop it))))))))))))

;; '("PROJECT=\"odt\""
;;   "PROJECT=\"odt\""
;;   "URL=\"https://github.com/kjambunathan/org-mode-ox-odt/issues/251\""
;;   "URL=\"https://github.com/kjambunathan/org-mode-ox-odt/issues/261\""
;;   "PROJECT=\"ods\""
;;   "PROJECT=\"ods\""
;;   "URL=\"https://github.com/kjambunathan/org-mode-ox-odt/issues/235\""
;;   "URL=\"https://github.com/kjambunathan/org-mode-ox-odt/issues/253\""
;;   )

(setq org-tags-history
      (append my-org-agenda-prop-filters
              org-tags-history))
```